# How to 404 redirect within zend framework from bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, bootstrapping

I've got an app with custom routes - in case a URL that's not available is called, an exception is thrown. In the catch block, I'm trying to

- send an 404 error
- show a custom not found page (available via /notfound)

How can I achieve that? If I redirect to that page, it always does a 302 redirect ... - my idea then was to kind of render the notfound view from within bootstrap

Thanks!

Comment: You can't "redirect" to a 404 page. A redirect (HTTP status 302 or 301), by definition, is not a 404. Also, ZF should do what you are after by default, if this is ZF1, take a look at the error controller.

Answer (score 0):

My way of doing: 

1- In `public`, i add a file `redirect404.html` with a specific message about 4040 error.

2- In my `ErrorController` in the `errorAction()` I do something like:

```
    $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

    if (!$errors || !$errors instanceof ArrayObject) {
        $this->view->message = 'You have reached the error page';
        return;
    }
    $redirect404 = false;

    switch ($errors->type) {
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:
            // 404 error -- controller or action not found
            $httpCode = 404;
            $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
            $redirect404 = true;
            break;    
    ....        
    }
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode($httpCode);
    $this->getResponse()->clearBody();
  ...

  if (APPLICATION_ENV != 'development') {
      if ($redirect404)
          $this->_redirect('./../redirect404.html'); // with Static page
      ....
   }

  // If you want a dynamic page use your error.phtml
  // and use $this->view like any other controller
```

3 - In your code throw the good exception.

I hope it will help you

Comment: Why would you redirect to a static HTML page, when the error controller is perfectly capable of rendering its own template with the same content?

Comment: @TimFountain: You're absolutely right.
Say about the project that I have here, it is a static page, so I propose this solution, but of course, the controller does (I use for errors that are not 404 and 403)